# I have problem with navigation bar and container in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am new to bootstrap, and right now i'm trying to make a navigation bar, so i code this :

```
        <nav class="row navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-white">
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
                <img src="Frontend/Images/Logo.png" alt="Logo" >
            </a>
            <button 
                class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right"
                type="button"
                data-toggle="collapse"
                data-target="#navb"
            >
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navb">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item mx-md-2">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link active">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item mx-md-2">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Paket Travel</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item mx-md-2">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Testimonial</a>
                    </li>   
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

but it turns out the buttons are not in the container or navbar. What did i do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The navbar was looking good the only thing that you had done wrong is give the class row to the nav.
As you can see in the image it gives another 100% width. That is why there was so much space

[image]

You had `<nav class="row navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-white">`

Change it to      `<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-white">`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, it brings my motivation back